# Can 1 matrix represent 2 different linear maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I understand that matrices represent linear maps and all of the exercises I have done have been representing a specific example linear map with a matrix.

It got me wondering: can a unique matrix represent 2 different linear maps (i.e., can 2 different linear maps be represented by the same matrix)? If it is possible, could someone give me an example?

Thank you!

Comment: This is an excellent question

Comment: Yes, of course if you use different bases for the matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $V$ and $V'$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces (it may be the case that $V=V'$). A linear map $F\colon V\to W$ is completely specified by the assignment of **three** pieces of information: an "input" basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$, an "output" basis $\mathcal{B}'$ of $V'$, and a matrix $A$ with appropriate dimension. Changing one of these, while letting the other two fixed, may result in the prescription of a different linear map (there are exceptions, such as the null map $F\equiv 0$).

For example, consider the map $F\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ given by
$$ 
F(x, y)=(x+y, x-y).$$
Taking $\mathcal B=\mathcal B'=\{(1,0), (0, 1)\}$, this map is associated to the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1& -1\end{bmatrix}$. However, changing $\mathcal{B}'$ to $\{(1, 1), (1, -1)\}$, the associated matrix is now $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

**ADDENDUM**. Here I wrote an example of two matrices associated to the same linear map. The same blue print can produce two linear maps associated to the same matrix.

**A RELATED PROBLEM**. An interesting classic problem is the following. Let a finite-dimensional vector space $V\ne \{0\}$ be fixed. Are there linear maps $F\colon V\to V$ such that their associated matrix is the same with respect to all bases? Note that here we only consider maps of $V$ into itself, and we require the same basis in input and in output.

(The answer is that such maps are precisely the **scalar maps**, that is, the ones of the form $F(v)=\lambda v$ for all $v\in V$.)